# Which .eslintrc do I need?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm fixing an issue that's documented here https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/788 where I need to replace `"parser": "babel-eslint",`  with `"parser": "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/babel-eslint",` 
The thing is `.eslintrc` isn't located anywhere within my CRA project. I checked with `ls -al` since this file is hidden by default.

So I ran `locate .eslintrc` and got extensive output:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/node_modules/debug/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/@humanwhocodes/object-schema/.eslintrc.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/ajv/scripts/.eslintrc.yml
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/array-includes/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/array.prototype.flat/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/array.prototype.flatmap/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/asn1.js/.eslintrc.js
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/bfj/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/body-parser/node_modules/debug/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/call-bind/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/cipher-base/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/color-name/.eslintrc.json
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/compression/node_modules/debug/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/deep-equal/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/define-properties/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/detect-port-alt/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/detect-port-alt/node_modules/debug/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/es-abstract/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/es-abstract/operations/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/es-to-primitive/.eslintrc
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/es5-ext/promise/.eslintrc.json
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/es5-ext/test/.eslintrc.json
-- rest omitted --
```

How do I recognize which one I need to edit ?

**Edit:**
well my components are throwing syntax error and the problem brought me to the aforementioned thread. Error output I'm getting:

```
src/components/NavBar.jsx                                                                                                                                                                                  
Syntax error: require() of ES Module /usr/src/app/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/es                                                                                                                      
lint-scope/lib/definition.js from /usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-eslint/lib/require-                                                                                                                      
from-eslint.js not supported. (0:undefined)                                                                                                                                                                
Instead change the require of definition.js in /usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-eslint                                                                                                                      
/lib/require-from-eslint.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS                                                                                                                       
modules                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
src/components/UserStatus.jsx                                                                                                                                                                              
Syntax error: require() of ES Module /usr/src/app/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/es                                                                                                                      
lint-scope/lib/definition.js from /usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-eslint/lib/require-                                                                                                                      
from-eslint.js not supported. (0:undefined)                                                                                                                                                                
Instead change the require of definition.js in /usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-eslint                                                                                                                      
/lib/require-from-eslint.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS                                                                                                                       
modules                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
src/components/UsersList.jsx                                                                                                                                                                               
Syntax error: require() of ES Module /usr/src/app/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/es                                                                                                                      
lint-scope/lib/definition.js from /usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-eslint/lib/require-                                                                                                                      
from-eslint.js not supported. (0:undefined)                                                                                                                                                                
Instead change the require of definition.js in /usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-eslint                                                                                                                      
/lib/require-from-eslint.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS                                                                                                                       
modules                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
src/index.js                                                                                                                                                                                               
Syntax error: require() of ES Module /usr/src/app/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/es                                                                                                                      
lint-scope/lib/definition.js from /usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-eslint/lib/require-                                                                                                                      
from-eslint.js not supported. (0:undefined)                                                                                                                                                                
Instead change the require of definition.js in /usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-eslint                                                                                                                      
/lib/require-from-eslint.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS                                                                                                                       
modules                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
src/reportWebVitals.js                                                                                                                                                                                     
Syntax error: require() of ES Module /usr/src/app/node_modules/eslint/node_modules/es                                                                                                                      
lint-scope/lib/definition.js from /usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-eslint/lib/require-                                                                                                                      
from-eslint.js not supported. (0:undefined)                                                                                                                                                                
Instead change the require of definition.js in /usr/src/app/node_modules/babel-eslint                                                                                                                      
/lib/require-from-eslint.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS                                                                                                                       
modules                                                                                                                                                                                                    
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
                                                                                                                                                                                                           
ERROR: Service 'client' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c npm run build' retur                                                                                                                      
ned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: I think you should probably back up because this seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). CRA installs all the dependencies it needs, including the parser, and using a different version from outside could cause different problems. Also editing files in node_modules/ is a generally bad idea, because those edits won't necessarily persist through installs or appear on other machines (e.g. in CI).

Comment: seams more like a problem with your imports inside the components. are you using `require()`? you should use `import` instead. like the error says.

Comment: I'm not using `require()` anywhere in my code. More likely some of the dependencies I'm using are using it under the hood.

Comment: Did you install eslint as a dependency instead of making it a development dependency?

Comment: @Sulthan  Yes. I installed it with `--save` flag not `--save-dev` flag.

Comment: I've made it a dev dependency but it threw the same error.